Fix android studio Inspect code tool mark every layout and imege resources unused when i used Viewbinding
I used ViewBinding on my project; I wan't find all unused layout or image with Inspect Code Tool, But id marked all layout and image resource is unused.
Is there other way to find unused resource?
my gradle version:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
